# Backtrack 5 R2 Dual-Boot w/Windows 7 No Longer Loads

Tags: windows, dual-boot

A while back, I installed Backtrack 5 R2 to Dual Boot on a Windows 7 PC. It worked fine for a while, but now when I try to load it, the screen gets all messed up (tried to get a picture with my phone, but it wasn't working too well). The last line before it freezes says:

```
fb: conflicting fb hw usage: nouveaufb vs VESA VGA - removing generic driver
```

Since it last worked, the only changes I can think of are that the computer is now connected via the ethernet cable to the router, and I upgraded the graphics card (to Nvidia). Because of the last line, I personally would put my money on the latter, but I still have no clue how to fix this. Can someone help me?

Comment: Not that it helps your current situation, but there are newer versions that might be work looking at, namely Backtrack 5 R3 and Kali.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you're having problems with your new graphics card. Your system is trying to load the driver called `nouveau`, but it is not working. Because of the `fb`, I think this error happens in the early stages of the boot process.

You should try to install the driver delivered by Nvidia itself.

To do so, you could try [these instructions](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=44433) (the second post of that thread would be useful to you).

---

**Update:**
I copy below those instructions. They were written in that forum by user maverik35, on April 09<sup>th</sup>, 2011.

- Enter the safe mode or text mode.
- Uninstall the `nouveau` driver.
- Blacklist it

  - In `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, just type `blacklist nouveau` in a new line.
- Install the nvidia driver (previously downloaded from nvidia website and according to your card model), just follow the instructions.
- Load these changes. You have two different ways to do so:

  - Startx the X's (`startx`)

    - If you startx and see some problems, you might want to do this:

> modprobe -r nouveau
>   modprobe nvidia.
>
> Just reboot (`reboot`) at prompt.
>
> - At startup, it will load all sistem with new nvidia driver.

Comment: This might seem like a stupid question, but how do I get into safe mode?  When the computer first boots up, I have the option of "recovery mode" and then the regular OS.  I gave recovery mode a shot, but it fails too.

Comment: You can use the install CD. It should give you the option *safe mode*.

Comment: But it is already installed on my computer?  Will the install cd do anything for me?

Comment: Read carefully this link: http://www.hackingdna.com/2012/02/things-you-should-know-about-backtrack.html.

Comment: Ok, so I did the Backtrack Debug - Safe Mode, but it still just froze